# Avoid accidental tap/touch in a Jetpack Compose Slider which is placed inside in a scrollable column

Tags: android, slider, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Slider which is placed inside a Column which is scrollable. When i scroll through the components sometimes accidentally slider value changes because of accidental touches. How can i avoid this?

1. Should i be disable taps on slider? If yes how can i do it?
2. Is there any alternate like Nested scroll instead of Column which can prevent this from happening?

   ```
   @Composable
   fun ColumnScope.FilterRange(
    title: String,
    range: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float>,
    rangeText: String,
    valueRange: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float>,
    onValueChange: (ClosedFloatingPointRange<Float>) -> Unit,
   ) {
   Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Size_Regular))

    Text(
       text = title,
       style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Size_X_Small))

    Text(
       text = rangeText,
       style = MaterialTheme.typography.subtitle1
   )

    RangeSlider(
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
       values = range,
       valueRange = valueRange,
       onValueChange = {
           onValueChange(it)
       })

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(Size_Small))

    Divider(thickness = DividerSize)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the RangeSlider and only enable it when you tap on it. You disable it by tapping anywhere else within the Column. This is a similar behavior used to mimic losing focus. Here's an example:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @ExperimentalMaterialApi
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {

            var rangeEndabled by remember { mutableStateOf(false)}.apply { this.value }
            var sliderPosition by remember { mutableStateOf(0f..100f) }
            Text(text = sliderPosition.toString())

            Column(modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTapGestures(
                        onTap = {
                            rangeEndabled = false
                        }
                    )
                }) {
                
                repeat(30) {
                    Text(it.toString())
                }

                RangeSlider(
                    enabled = rangeEndabled,
                    values = sliderPosition,
                    onValueChange = { sliderPosition = it },
                    valueRange = 0f..100f,
                    onValueChangeFinished = {
                        // launch some business logic update with the state you hold
                        // viewModel.updateSelectedSliderValue(sliderPosition)
                    },
                    modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
                        detectTapGestures(
                            onTap = {
                                rangeEndabled = true
                            }
                        )
                    }
                )

                repeat(30) {
                    Text(it.toString())
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Johann 

Is there any way that we can just completely stop tap gestures on sliders and keep only drag gestures?

Comment: Well a RangeSlider by default has dragging without tapping. You really can't have dragging of the slider while allowing scrolling of the list at the same time. Those are conflicting behaviors.

Comment: Actually I meant, I want to keep dragging but avoid slider value change when user taps on the slider. Only on drag, slider value should change. Is it possible @Johann ?

Comment: I understand what you want but you are creating conflicting behavior. You want vertical scrolling on the column and horizontal scrolling on the slider. While that is technically possible, it isn't in practice because scrolll events are captured in both directions simultaneously and users almost never do a perfect vertical scroll. They will have a certain degree of horizontal scroll as well and if they touch the slider while scrolling up, it will cause the slider also to be adjusted. I have never seen an app that includes a slider in vertical scrolling. Makes no sense.

Comment: If your screen is similar to a screen showing settings, you should just place an item on the screen that lists the purpose of the slider - like "Screen Brightness". The user then taps on that item and it brings up a dialog showing a slider along with an OK and Cancel button. This is a far better UI experience.